# Cannot retrieve path of Special Folders when redirection enabled

Tags: vb.net

I have a tool that reads a .txt file for a list of paths and uses them in a copy. It looks like this:

```
***DESTINATION***
E:\Backup
***Sources***
%USERPROFILE%\Pictures
%USERPROFILE%\Favourites
%USERPROFILE%\Contacts
%USERPROFILE%\My Videos
```

My system has folder redirection enabled so 'Pictures' for example is actually D:\Adam\Pictures. However when using the following code it will only resolve as C:\Adam\Pictures and throw a "Cannot find path error".

```
'Declarations earlier in script
Dim Destpath As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "\CONFIG.txt")(1)
Dim userprofilevar = (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile))

'Snippet of line reading logic     
            ElseIf line.Contains("%USERPROFILE%") Then
                Dim lineArray() As String = line.Split("\")
                Dim lineuser As String = userprofilevar + "\"
                Dim linepath As String = lineArray(1)
                line = lineuser + linepath
                Destpath = String.Concat(Destpath, "\", linepath)
                MessageBox.Show(Destpath)
            Else
```

Does anyone know how to resolve the correct path of the redirected folder through the %USERPROFILE% variable?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878605/Getting-All-Special-Folders-in-NET

Comment: @AlexB. Thanks! I was able to adapt your example to my code. Now my issue will be cross referencing what is on the line to check the `KnownFolders` and return the correct path in relation to whats is needed. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I´m very sorry but I just found the article. Maybe another can answer to that or you contact the author of the article.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found:

After converting @AlexB's example into VB.NET and getting it working in my app, I simply declared each of the `%Userprofile%` folders as a string then have the line reading logic update the `line` string as the correct folder path:

```
'Declarations as start of Form
Dim downloadsPath As String = KnownFolders.GetPath(KnownFolder.Downloads)
Dim contactspath As String = KnownFolders.GetPath(KnownFolder.Contacts)

'Snippit of line reading logic
            ElseIf line.Contains("%USERPROFILE%\Downloads") Then
                line = downloadspath
            ElseIf line.Contains("%USERPROFILE%\Contacts") Then
                line = contactspath
```

It's not pretty to do for all 11 `%Userprofile%` folders, but it works!